# ng-model changes the text in input field to [Object object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an input field that takes an address selected from googles autocomplete api.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="editing || creating" has-class="{'has-error': roomForm.address.$invalid && (roomForm.address.$touched || roomForm.$submitted)}">
                <input address-search selected-address="selectedAddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Where is your place located?" name="address" ng-model="room.address" required type="text">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="roomForm.address.$error.required && (roomForm.address.$touched || roomForm.$submitted)" role="alert">The room location is required</div>
            </div>
```

This is the directive that attaches the autocomplete to the input

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('addressSearch', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        addressSearch: '=',
        selectedAddress: '=selectedAddress'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var options = {
          types: ['address']
        };

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var address = autocomplete.getPlace();
          scope.selectedAddress(address);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

The problem is that when I select an address and then begin typing in another form element, the address in the input field will change into [Object object] instead of displaying the address I originally selected. I know that it is displaying that because it is trying to show the ng-model as a string, but how do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selectedAddress` is an object. You need to access a property on that object to get the string you're looking for.

Throw a `console.log(selectedAddress)` in there to see what the object looks like, and then find the property you need and use that on the `ng-model`, like `ng-model="room.address.foo.bar"`